# Does Constraint Layout Editor in Android Studio 3.1.x already support AndroidX?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I am using Android Studio 3.1.4. Recently I have updated my project to AndroidX. Since then it seems that Layout Editor in Android Studio ignores Constraint Layout and does not display the View Inspector with controls for width/height style, margins, and bias in Attributes Window as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor#edit-properties) (the first group of controls). Basically I do not see any controls related to Constraint Layout - e.g. the toolbar with buttons to configure the layout appearance in the editor as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor#intro). I am able to build and run the app without any issues. My only problem is that I am not able to update my layouts by means of the Layout Editor anymore. Is anyone able to successfully use AndroidX ConstraintLayout in combination with Android Studio Layout Editor?

**build.gradle**

```
// ...    

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    // ...

}

dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.2'
    //...
}
```

**Layout Editor**

[image: Android Studio Layout Editor]

Comment: Android Studio 3.2 might support it. Android Studio 3.3 damn well better support it. Android Studio 3.1 probably doesn't, as IIRC it predated AndroidX.

Comment: I have not managed to make it work in Android Studio 3.1.x hence I have tried Android Studio 3.2 Beta 5 and the Layout Editor seems to be working correctly with Constraint Layout.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need use Android Studio 3.2 or 3.3